# How to get GCDWebServerBodyReaderCompletionBlock synchronously?

Tags: gcdwebserver

I'm working on a proxy-kind thing, which should make a request via NSURLSession and progressively transfer it to the GCDWebServer response.

The issue is with `GCDWebServerStreamedResponse responseWithContentType:asyncStreamBlock` – it requires a content type, so must be called after I got a headers. And it returns a completion block asynchronously for some reason, while the data could be received faster.

I mean, now it works this way:

1. API makes a call to GCDWebServer
2. GCDWebServer creates a NSURLSession data task
3. data task receive headers
4. create GCDWebServerStreamedResponse
5. receive data chunk (which I want to push into the streamed response)
6. got the completion block from step 4

How can I get the completion block right after step 4?

Sorry if I've missed any info, just I'm stuck with it and almost sure I'm doing something wrong way...

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `NSMutableData` as an intermediary buffer: whenever data arrives from the `NSURLSession`, append to it, and whenever `GCDWebServerAsyncStreamBlock` is called, return that buffer and create a new empty one.

Just be sure to lock the access to that buffer with a `NSLock` or a GCD serial queue.

Comment: How can I do that with no content-type?

Comment: Yep, but it looks like a dirty hack, at least I'm asking here exactly to avoid that way…

Comment: It's not a hack at all: you're trying to make 2 asynchronous systems work together, so you need a shared "state" which here is a `NSMutableData` object.

Comment: I don't see a reason why creating an async response should be asynchronous and why it has to have content-type immediately on creation. Why it's not possible to create the response an then later send headers and so on?

Comment: `GCDWebServerAsyncStreamBlock ` is a just a utility class that makes some assumptions. If you want more control, go directly to `GCDWebServerResponse` and `<GCDWebServerBodyReader>`. You can read more about the architecture of GCDWebServer in the README.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to dig deeper, but their readme does not provide any detailed info, just basic examples, unfortunatelly…